# Create Customer Statement in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have tables one is invoice & other is payment, I want to make customer statement related to it

`Invoice` table:

```
Invoice Date:
Invoice Id:
Customer Id:
quantity:
Rate:
Amount:
```

`Payment` table

```
Payment Date
Customer Id:
Payment Method:
Reference No:
Payment Amount:
```

I want to create a customer statement like

```
Date | Invoice Detail | Debit Amount | Credit Amount|
```

Date From Invoice or Payment Column according to data

Invoice amount should be debit & payment amount should be credit to form the ledger, How could i do with that Please help me out

I got the balance invoice sheet etc , but cant able to make ledger / statement of customer

Database file https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnra30rpgdlzz56/invoice-test.accdb

Comment: I'm a bit confused how your tables link together. Shouldn't `Payment` be linked to an `Invoice` rather than a `Customer`?

Comment: The system needs some way of linking payments and invoices. An invoice could be paid in multiple payments and a payment could relate to multiple invoices! Unless you just want a chronological list of of amounts invoiced and amounts paid, each on a seperate line. In that case you'd need a `UNION` query to generate a dataset containing both types of transaction.

Comment: I just want invoice & payment to be deducted in ledger, dont want to relate with invoices, & how to make UNION query with that data as i m beginner of MS access

Comment: I just looked at  the database and it bears no resemblance to your question from what I can see.  The question mentions tables `Invoice` and `Payment`, listing the relevant fields but I see neither in the database.  Please ensure your question is precise, this is not an "upload & fix it for free" service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This answer was constructed on the basis of the requirements and table definitions posted in the question.  Upon inspection of the Access DB provided, the table structures described in the question bear little resemblance to the real implementation, however the approach still solves what was requested.

---

The base query is something along these lines.

```
SELECT [Customer ID], 'DEBIT' AS Transaction_Type, [Invoice Date], [Invoice Id] As [Ref_Num], [Amount] as [Debit], Null AS [Credit]
FROM Invoice
UNION
SELECT [Customer ID], 'CREDIT' AS Transaction_Type, [Invoice Date], [Reference No] As [Ref_Num], Null as [Debit], [Payment Amount] AS [Credit]
FROM Payment
```

If you want to aggregate all debit/credit transactions for a particular date it becomes fiddly as you need to merge the references, but in essence this is what you need.

I've not been able to test this so please advise if it works for you.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnra30rpgdlzz56/invoice-test.accdb kindly study this database, what i had made and want to make statmenet of buyers thorugh invoie & cheque database

Comment: As I commented below your question, it is necessary to be specific when wording your problem to save contributors from wasting their time.  There is no table `Cheque`, no table `invoie` and the field names you specified do not exist in the tables which I assume you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry my mistake i have to write exactly what i have made , i have done Union Query it working but just have an issue that from credit column its showing value in other language , i can't able to change its format

Comment: SELECT [INV SHEET Query].Customer, 'DEBIT' AS Transaction_Type, [Date], [INV AMT] as [Debit], Null AS [Credit]
FROM [INV SHEET Query]
UNION SELECT payment.Customer, 'CREDIT' AS Transaction_Type, payment.date, Null as [Debit], Format(payment.payment, "##,##0.00") AS [Credit]
FROM  payment;

Done this Thanks Alot Matt Weller